# `curl --header $1` と同じことを Swift で実現したい (NSURLSessionのヘッダの記述)

Tags: swift, http, nsurlsession

以下の `curl` のコマンドを Swift で実現したいです。しかしヘッダ部分の記述方法がわかりません。

```
curl -X GET \
     --header "X-Auth-Token: abcdef" \
     https://devapi.thecurrencycloud.com/v2/rates/detailed?buy_currency=EUR&sell_currency=USD&fixed_side=buy&amount=1000
```

こちらが私のコードです。しかしエラーとなってしまいました。解決方法をご教示頂きたいです。

```
func exchangerate(){
    let token = "abcdef"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://devapi.thecurrencycloud.com/v2/rates/detailed")!)
    var buyCurrency = "EUR"
    var sellCurrency = "USD"
    var fixSide = "buy"
    var amount = "1000"
    var postString:NSString = "buy_currency=\(buyCurrency)&sell_currency=\(sellCurrency)&fixed_side=\(fixSide)&amount=\(amount)"

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseStringExchangeRate = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseStringExchangeRate = \(responseStringExchangeRate)")
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

エラー:

```
error=Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain 
      Code=-1005 
      "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)" 
      UserInfo=0x7fea7b4d63f0
      {
         NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://devapi.thecurrencycloud.com/v2/rates/detailed,
        NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://devapi.thecurrencycloud.com/v2/rates/detailed,             _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4,
        _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, 
        NSUnderlyingError=0x7fea7d805ba0
        "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1005.)"
      }
```

Comment: 以前の質問に解決マークを付けていただくと、次に回答する人が安心しますよ。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
質門に解決マークを付けるとは、評価(数字)の下の✓をクリックすることで宜しいでしょうか？
それであれば恐縮ですが、あの回答は質門者である私自身が行ったものなので、回答から48時間は私はチェックを押せないようです。
あと23時間経ちましたら、チェック致します。
煩わせてしまい申し訳ございません。

Comment: ああ、ごく昨日のことなのですね。私の確認漏れです。失礼しました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`request.HTTPMethod = "POST"` ですかね？</s>

以下を test.swift として保存。(以下、修正します)

```
import Foundation

func exchangerate(){
    let token = "abcdef"
    // let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://devapi.thecurrencycloud.com/v2/rates/detailed")!)
    var buyCurrency = "EUR"
    var sellCurrency = "USD"
    var fixSide = "buy"
    var amount = "1000"
    //var postString:NSString = "buy_currency=\(buyCurrency)&sell_currency=\(sellCurrency)&fixed_side=\(fixSide)&amount=\(amount)"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://devapi.thecurrencycloud.com/v2/rates/detailed?buy_currency=\(buyCurrency)&sell_currency=\(sellCurrency)&fixed_side=\(fixSide)&amount=\(amount)")!)


    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    //request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Auth-Token")
    // request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            println("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        println("response = \(response)")

        let responseStringExchangeRate = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseStringExchangeRate = \(responseStringExchangeRate)")
    }
    task.resume()
}

// for debug.
exchangerate()
sleep(10)
```

実行。

```
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift test.swift
response = <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f8390793810> { URL: https://devapi.thecurrencycloud.com/v2/rates/detailed } { status code: 401, headers {
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 176;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Wed, 07 Jan 2015 00:11:17 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
    "X-Request-Id" = 2693396219771410479;
} }
responseStringExchangeRate = Optional({"error_code":"auth_failed","error_messages":{"username":[{"code":"invalid_supplied_credentials","message":"Authentication failed with the supplied credentials","params":{}}]}})
$
```

### 追記

(以下、ちょっと乱暴な説明です、ごめんなさい)

質問にあった GET でのリクエストは、サーバに対して、

```
GET /v2/rates/detailed HTTP/1.1
Host: devapi.thecurrencycloud.com
X-Auth-Token: abcdef
(空行)
buy_currency=EUR&sell_currency=USD&fixed_side=buy&amount=1000
```

のような文字列を送信しているのだと思います。

対して私が回答したものは、

```
GET /v2/rates/detailed?buy_currency=EUR&sell_currency=USD&fixed_side=buy&amount=1000 HTTP/1.1
Host: devapi.thecurrencycloud.com
X-Auth-Token: abcdef
(空行)
```

という文字列を送信します。

また、POST の場合は、

```
POST /v2/rates/detailed HTTP/1.1
Host: devapi.thecurrencycloud.com
X-Auth-Token: abcdef
(空行)
buy_currency=EUR&sell_currency=USD&fixed_side=buy&amount=1000
```

といった文字列を送信します。

(空行)以前が、いわゆるHTTP リクエストヘッダで、以降はリクエストボディ(request.HTTPBody)です。

サーバ側で、GET でリクエストを受けたなら、 リクエストボディは読まないで、レスポンスをしてしまうのだと思います。また、POST であれば、リクエストボディまでちゃんと読んでくれてたのだと思います。

なので、エラーメッセージが

`"The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1005.)`

となって、「まだ、サーバに話したいことがあるのに(リクエストボディを送っていないのに)。。」(超意訳)

となったのだと思います。

Comment: アドバイス、誠にありがとうございます。
POSTとすれば接続できますね。
こちらが参考にしているドキュメントです。こちらにはGETと書いてあるため、そのようにしておりました。
https://connect.currencycloud.com/documentation/getting-started/cookbook

しかしながら、POSTとすると現状のコードでは求めている情報が得られないようです。これからそちらの問題の解決に取り組みます。
恐縮ですが、解決済にするのは求める情報が得られるまで待っていただけましたら幸いに存じます。

Comment: あら、request.HTTPMethod を設定してたので POST がしたいものだと思ってました。回答に追記します。

Comment: 出来ました！ありがとうございます！
しかし１つ質門があります。どうして私のコードではエラーがでたのでしょうか？
GETのときは
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
という記述は使えないのですか？
ご教示いただければ幸いに存じます。

Comment: 動作できたとのこと、よかったです。疑問についても追記してみました。